# There is a better approach to make autofac register which database my service will use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, clean-architecture

**PLEASE READ THE EDIT SECTION, IT CAN HELP ME TO CLARIFY THE QUESTION**

I have this structure right now:

1. WebApp.csproj
2. Application.csproj
3. Data.csproj
4. Oracle.csproj
5. SqlServer.csproj

My Data (3) is just a project referenced by WebApp (1) to decides which one (4 or 5) should be called based on the web.config.
If the web.config contains the app.key DBaseDL with 'oracle' value, it should LoadAssembly 4, instead, assembly 5.

Classes of 4 and 5 are mirror but with the query on each syntax (4 has syntax for oracle and 5 for sql server). Those mirror classes implements a commom interface between then, like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Oracle
{
   public class User : IUser
   {
       //...
   }
}

namespace MyProject.SqlServer
{
   public class User : IUser
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

On Data (3) csproj I'm trying to create a Factory which creates the User class from 4 or 5, based on the web.config settings like I said before. So I do something like this:

```
public class UserDataFactory : IDataLayerFactory<IUser>
{
    private readonly string _key;
    public UserDataFactory(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    public IUser Create()
    {
        string strPath = string.Empty;
        string strClassName = string.Empty;
        string strAssemblyName = string.Empty;
        string strVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        if (_key.Equals("oracle"))
            strAssemblyName = "MyProjejct.Oracle";
        else
            strAssemblyName = "MyProject.SQLServer";

        strPath = strAssemblyName + ", Version=" + strVersion + ", Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx";
        strClassName = strAssemblyName + ".User";

        return (IUser)Assembly.Load(strPath).CreateInstance(strClassName);
    }
}
```

My problem starts on this IDataFactory class.
I already did everything works with forced values (like always on SQLServer or Oracle) but not with IoC + the settings key for database.

I'm trying to do something like this with AutoFac but I'm probably missing something and I'm blind.

```
public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<Mediator>().As<IMediator>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<AutofacValidatorFactory>().As<IValidatorFactory>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<AutofacDataLayerFactory>().As<IDataFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider>().As<ModelValidatorProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<RegistryManagerService>().As<IRegistryManagerService>().SingleInstance().WithParameter("appName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPNAME"]);

        builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
        {
            var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return t => c.Resolve(t);
        });

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyProj.Application"))
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Handler"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyProj.Application"))
           .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Validator"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyProj.Application"))
           .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("DataFactory"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Just to say, IDataFactory is about User now, but it will be a lot of things, and I don't want to register for every class again on autofac. I'm trying to register all my IDataFactory so the constructor of my handlers on Application.csproj should get the already created by factory classes, the DataAccess object from Oracle or SqlServer.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

After digging and learning a little more about the AutoFac, IoC and DI, I realize a easy way to register my class, but I'm pretty sure there is a better and more ellegant solution then mine.

I just read the key from configuration manager and write this code at the AutoFacConfig file:

```
if (key == "oracle")
    builder.RegisterType<DocspiderOracleDbService>().As<IDocspiderDbService>().InstancePerRequest();
else
    builder.RegisterType<DocspiderSqlServerDbService>().As<IDocspiderDbService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

This worked because only the service from the correct database is registered, but, I'll keep digging how to make it the right away.

If anyone have an idea, I'll be greatfull.

Comment: Have you [read the docs on registering open generics](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)?

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig! Thanks for your comment. Yes I did but maybe the concepts of how autofac works are a bit confusing on my mind yet. I'm reading again and again, trying to understand how everything works. Did you read my edit? If you can, give a check. Maybe I was asking wrong.